# Create/Delete a connection from javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Is it possible to create a [Connection](http://blog.xrm.com/index.php/2011/06/connections-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011/) from javascript through the REST services (or another method)?

I can't find a great deal of support on this at all.

Anyone done something similar?

I'm using this as I want to add a Custom role to multiple selected contacts.

EDIT:
I currently launch a HTML web resource, iterate through the selected GUIDs and create association rules. At this stage I wanted to trigger a workflow to manage which welcome email should be sent out as well as other things. As I can't seem to trigger a workflow on the creation of an association I'm now looking at using connections so updating my JS to create / remove those instead of the associations. This way I can trigger a workflow. However don't know how to create a connection in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ajax/dwr for this purpose. Although it is very shady that you have to create a connection in javascript. could help more if a reason or use case is provided.